# How do we define in general a set inductively within ZFC set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Let $s$ be a variable. Let $X$ some arbitrary set and $\phi(x)$ be a formula of the form:

$$x\in s\to f_1(x)\in s\quad\land \quad x\in s\to f_2(x)\in s \quad\land \quad...$$

I am wondering how we should define a set

$$s=\{x\in X :\phi(x)\}$$

It seems to me that we can't just use the axiom of specification, which states:

$$\forall p_1,...,p_n,\forall X,\exists s, \forall x, (x\in s \iff (x\in X \land \phi (x,p_1,...,p_n)))$$

The reason we can't use this I think, is that $s$ is not a free variable in $\phi$ here.

**So given that we can't use the the axiom schema of replacement, how in general do we define an inductively defined set in ZFC set theory?**

Comment: By "define" I am assuming you mean: prove that there exists such sets. So pick your favorite $s_0$, and close this $s_0$ under your $f_i$'s in $\omega$ steps using recursion. This will give you some $s$ which contains $s_0$ and you can see that it satifies $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

There may not exist such a set with the conditions you gave.

Consider $X=\{\emptyset\}$ and $\phi(x)\equiv x\in s\to x\cup\{x\}\in s$.

Now $s=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\}$ implies $s\subseteq X$. The only subsets of $X$ are the empty set and $X$ itself. So let's test which of them is possible.

Assume $s=\emptyset$. Then $\phi(x)$ is vacuously true for any $x$, and therefore $s=X$, in contradiction to $s=\emptyset$. Therefore $s\ne\emptyset$.

Assume $s=X$. Then $\emptyset\in X$. But then, by definition, we have $\emptyset\in s\to\emptyset\cup\{\emptyset\}\in s$, that is, $X\in s$, in contradiction to $s=X$.

Therefore there does not exist a set $s$ which fulfils those conditions.

Now one can observe that this example fails because there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\notin X$. Therefore one might think of fixing this by demanding that all $f_i$ are functions $f_i:X\to X$.

In that case, $s=X$ fulfils all conditions, as $\phi(x)$ then is true for all $x\in X$ by additional condition, and clearly $X=\{x\in X:\mathrm{True}\}$.

But to serve as definition, $s$ would also have to be unique, and that may not be the case for this amended definition. To see this, consider $X=\{\emptyset, A\}$ for some arbitrary $A\ne\emptyset$, and just one function in $\phi$, which is $f(x)=\emptyset$ for all $x$.

Then both $s=\{\emptyset\}$ and $s=X$ fulfill the conditions.

However one can observe that the intersection of any non-zero number of sets that fulfil the conditions will always fulfil the condition, too. Therefore one can change the condition slightly, by having $\phi$ take the set as second argument:
$$\phi(x,y) \equiv x\in y\to f_1(x)\in y \land x\in y\to f_2(x)\in y \land \ldots$$
Now you can use the axiom of specification on the *power set* of $X$ to define an auxiliary set as follows:
$$A = \{y\in \mathcal P(X): \forall x\in X\, \phi(x,y)\}$$
Now your inductively defined set is the intersection of all members of $A$.

Comment: Yes, that was why I deleted my comment. In any case, in a more general framework, the $X$ is not really important, since given any number of class functions $f_i:V \rightarrow V$ and any $s_0$, we can find $s$ containing $s_0$, which is closed under $f_i$, using just recursion and replacement.

Comment: "*There may not exist such a set with the conditions you gave.*" you have convinced me that this is true. However, I have often seen written down something like this: "*Let the set of lambda terms be defined inductively as follows: 1. If $t$ in $V$ then $t$ in $L$. 2. If $u$ and $v$ in $L$ then $uv$ in $L$. 3. If $u$ in $L$ and $v$ in $V$ then $\lambda v, u$ in $L$."* They then don't justify that this set actually exists. But how should I think about this definition then? Are they implicitly making an unproven existence statement? How in general would we ahow its existence?

Comment: @user56834: In that description, clearly $L$ is *not* a subset of $V$. Instead, here $V$ is a subset of $L$, functioning as a “seed” of the complete set. That is, it doesn't play the role of $X$ in your construction, but gives another term in $\phi$, $x\in V\to x\in y$.

Comment: I didn't claim $V$ played the role of $X$. The role of $X$ is played by $(V\times \{\lambda, ","\})^*$. (note the star at the end, meaning "sequences of").

Comment: @user56834: In that case, the construction I described (with properly amended $\phi$) should work directly on that set.